# How to change animation speed when is playing?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have  `Animation` and i need to change duration or speed in run.
How to do this?

```
 Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
 fadeIn.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //add this
 fadeIn.setDuration(800);
 fadeIn.setFillEnabled(true);
 fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);

 bt1.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Interpolators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) to have a variable speed during animation. Example can be found [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/behold-the-animation-magic-of-an-android-interpolator/).

Comment: So which interpolator I used to change the speed?

Comment: Depends on how should the speed change. Do you want the speed to increase or decrease ?

Comment: decrease and i want to do it smooth :)

Comment: You can use DecelerateInterpolator in that case and experiment with various values of the factor that you pass to the constructor of DecelerateInterpolator.

Comment: thanks, how can i pass my values to decel. interpolator?

Comment: DecelerateInterpolator's constructor accept a float parameter : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.html#DecelerateInterpolator(float) You can vary the parameter to suit what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two animations with different speeds. After the first has finished, the second gets played.

```
Animation anim1 = new AlphaAnimation (1, 0.5F);
anim1.setDuration (600); //The slow part.
//set other things for anim1

Animation anim2 = new AlphaAnimation (0.5F, 0);
anim2.setDuration (200); //The fast part.
//set other things for anim2
```

Comment: Yes, but probably it will be a very sharply look?